# redis key expired before its expire time

Tags: php, redis

Why is my redis key expired ahead of expire time? Here is my code:

```
$redisMaster = new Clredis();
$redisMaster->Redis_connect('M');
$redisMaster->Redis_Set("acceptedvals_".$MatriId,$acceptkey,2592000); //for 30days
```

But it expired before 30 days.

Comment: Perhaps the server was low on RAM and that key was evicted? Some of the eviction policies (e.g. `volatile-lru`) do that.

Comment: Not able to find that..

Comment: Look in your redis.conf file for the line that says `maxmemory-policy` or do a `CONFIG GET maxmemory-policy`.

Comment: Am not having the privilege to check...